# Server setup and create software/app on computer

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

How do I create a program that will make my local app available? (I do not want my app to be available without the program/application being turned on) .

For example, as `localhost/phpmyadmin`. It becomes available only after you have started MYSQL, on XAMPP for example. If you try to visit `localhost/phpmyadmin` WITHOUT launching Apache on XAMPP, you will receive following message:

> "phpMyAdmin tried to establish a connection to the MySQL server, but
>   the server denied the connection. Verify host, username and password
>   in your configuration and make sure that they match the information of
>   the MySQL server administrator."

I have an app on my local host (`localhost/myapp`) and of course it is always available as long as XAMPP is running. But I want it to only become available when it is turned on. Otherwise, show an error-like message.

Comment: This is much too broad for [SO]. It's not terribly clear what you want to do, but it sounds like it involves more than a single coding question.

Comment: @jdv Hello, and thanks for your reply. How about some info about how I can "reserve" the url "localhost/myapp"? (Or just "myapp" if it's possible) I can start with that.

Comment: Formatted URLs as code, error message as quote.  Modified tags for better visibility.

Comment: Your application is a web application, so nothing can prevent a user from starting a browser and typing `localhost/myapp` in it.  Only solution would be to ensure XAMPP is started at boot time.  Anyway, if XAMPP is down, you will not even get the message you saw, Apache will be down as well.